# ankhsvn changelist

Tags: svn, ankhsvn

What is the purpose of the changelist?

And is there a way to revert file in a changelist in ankhsvn?

Comment: Are you talking of the "Pending changes" list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The changelist feature of Subversion is a way to group a set of files with changes in a logical combination. (You can see these same lists in other Subversion clients).

In AnkhSVN you see the changelists as separate groups in the commit dialogs. And the files in the 'ignore-on-commit' group are by default not selected for commit.

Comment: thanks for the reply,
so is it possible to revert a changelist? or does that even make sense?

Comment: Because the files in the Pending Changes dialog are grouped by change list, you can just select the files in that group and revert them.